# Pulling User Object's Primary SMTP from ProxyAddresses

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a PS script that is pulling Employee IDs from a CSV file that I update every morning that I get from HR just to make sure the automation is running correctly by adding/changing their email, extensionAttribute 1, and the ProxyAddresses. I would like it to only check for the Primary SMTP instead of all ProxyAddresses but am having trouble.

`Import-Csv "C:\temp\HRfeed101519.csv" | foreach {Get-ADUser $_.EmpID -Properties * | fL mail, extensionattribute1, Proxyaddresses}`

Comment: Please, please, do not use `-Properties *`, query only for what's needed.

Answer (score 3):

The `ProxyAddresses` field identifies the `PrimarySMTPAddress` with the `SMTP:` tag. Therefore, you can query for that specifically and output it as a calculated property.

```
Get-ADUser $_.EmpID -prop ProxyAddresses,Mail,ExtensionAttribute1 |
    Select-Object Mail,ExtensionAttribute1,ProxyAddresses,
    @{Name='PrimarySMTPAddress';Expression={$_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP:' -creplace 'SMTP:'}}
```

`-cmatch` and `-creplace` perform ***case-sensitive*** regex matching.

---

**Note:** The default table display of the output may not show all of the properties and values due to collection size stored in `ProxyAddresses`. You can pipe your output to `Format-List` to see all properties, ***but do not store the `Format-List` output in a variable.***

Comment: @robdy, Thanks. I added a note for that situation.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I added the full key names to the hash table.